# Do nations with large dog eating populations still have dogs as pets?

Tags: dogs

Worldwide over 25 million dogs are eaten legally in non-emergency conditions by humans every year. Dogs are most popular in Chinese cuisine. China accounts for 40% of all dogs sold for culinary purposes, with South Korean as a close 2nd.

Having said that, I'm curious if the countries that consider dogs a normal part of their diet also keep them as pets?

I'm asking because I have a job where almost everyone I interact with was born in raised in such places and to my knowledge the ones who have pets only have cats, though it could be a coincidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked with a man from South Korea, he said that people keep cats and dogs as pets and those are not eaten. They have large dog farms (like our cattle farms) for eating, I would assume same goes for cats but he only talked about dogs.

Comment: The dog that eaten in Korea is a specific breed of dog that people usually don't keep as pets.  So there is that cultural distinction.

Answer (score 1):

America has a large pork eating population, yet some breeds of pig are kept as pets and some individuals of breeds normally raised for food may be pets.

The same species -- and the same breed -- may be meat animal, work animal, lab animal, pet. It isn't even unheard of for a single animal to occupy more than one of these roles at different times in its life.

Many American city-dwellers don't like thinking about that. Sorry.

Comment: This doesn't address the question and is more social commentary

Comment: I believe it does address the question, by pointing out that there is no inherent conflict between eating members of a species and keeping them as pets, even in cultures which are much farther removed from the realities of life than the Asian countries are. You're free to downvote if you disagree.

Comment: point taken - I have rescinded my downvote.